# how to add an L1 Regularization on the likelihood when use pymc3 to sample a MCMC?

Tags: python, pymc3, regularized

When I use pymc3 to do a sparse regression, I would like to add an L1 regularization to the objective function. How to achieve this in pymc3?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, one doesn't need to add it to the objective manually: regularization in Bayesian inference is a matter of choosing priors.  Gaussian priors on the regression coefficients are mathematically equivalent to L<sub>2</sub> regularization. **The mathematical equivalent of L<sub>1</sub> regularization is to use Laplace priors**, which are [available in PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/continuous.html#pymc3.distributions.continuous.Laplace).